# Raise a OnTextChanged event in winforms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I raise an event that will call my OnTextChanged overridden method for my textbox control?

edit:

```
private void thebox_TextChanged(object sender, FastColoredTextBoxNS.TextChangedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Why not just call the `OnTextChanged` handler directly?

Comment: By running the solution and changing text in the text-box!!!!

Comment: I have a custom TextBox that has special event args that I do not want to try and recreate, I was hoping I could just raise the event and let it do it itself. @Amit Mittal, no shit?

Comment: @user1596244: I think the point Amit Mittal may have been trying to make was... Raising a UI event is a matter of responding to something that happens in the UI.  In general, it _shouldn't_ be raised manually.  If you have some functionality in the event handler that should be common with other logical paths then it doesn't belong in the event handler.  It belongs in a common method which is called by both the event handler and any other logical paths that need it.

Comment: @user1596244 Can you emphasize on your comment about 'special' event args? May be including this part along with some code sample in the question can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to raise that event from the code behind is by making a change to the Text property of the TextBox.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx
[image]

Comment: You're correct, and this is technically an answer to the question, but it's a very bad idea. It's never a good plan to update text on a UI element just so you can activate some side effect that is unrelated to that text.

Answer (score 2):

When you find the need to try to call events directly, it usually indicates that you are trying to stuff to much logic into your event methods or event handlers. It is not a good idea to call OnTextChanged or call the event handler directly. Events are designed to be triggered based on user interaction, not to be called as normal methods whenever you want to see their side effects. In fact, it should be a design goal to remove all significant side effects from your event methods and all of your event handlers and move them into separate methods.

Your best option is to take the logic that is currently occurring in your OnTextChanged method and put it in another method, properly named. The method name "OnTextChanged" implies that it doesn't do anything except notify you that the text has changed. If you need to do more work, put it in its own method (for example, UpdateRelatedControls, or whatever it may be) and call this new method from your OnTextChanged event. You can then expose this new method publicly and call it any time you want.

Comment: OnTextChanged is where I use regexs to determine which characters to color and to not color, also where to place code folders. When I open another form the user changes what and where code folders are placed but this does not update the current folders until the user changes the text. So I wanted to call ontextchanged after the user closes the folding markers form so that they see the changes right away.

Comment: Changing text color and folders isn't really directly related to the text changing - those are side effects. I would create an UpdateColorsAndFolders method and call it from OnTextChanged. Then you can also call the UpdateColorsAndFolders method when the user closes the other form so they see their changes. That way you don't have to try to call OnTextChanged when the text really hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

To format numbers to decimal format with commas on `textchanged` event. Here is the code in c#

```
private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        //Remove previous formatting, or the decimal check will fail 

        string value = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", double.Parse(textBox8.Text));
 // "12,345.87"


        decimal ul;
        //Check we are indeed handling a number 
        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out ul))
        {
            //Unsub the event so we don't enter a loop 
            textBox8.TextChanged -= textBox8_TextChanged;
            //Format the text as currency 
            textBox8.Text = value.ToString();
            textBox8.TextChanged += textBox8_TextChanged;
        }

    }
```